# Prevent Excel from modifying dataconnection

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerpivot

I have a weird and frustrating situation: I created a PowerPivot based on SQL Server tables. I have chosen for the SQLNCLI11 provider.

All works well on my laptop, but when a colleague opens the sheet on his own pc and wants to refresh the data, Excel complains that the provider is not registered on the machine. This is the first weird thing: I installed the SQL Server Native Client provider with the right bit version. But the message persists even after a reboot.

To get around this situation, I changed the provider using the steps described in
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2955369/cannot-modify-the-odata-connections-in-an-excel-2013-powerpivot-workbo

Now, the weird and frustrating thing: when I (or my colleague) refresh the data, Excel changes back the provider. Why?

This is the original situation:

[image]

I then change the connection: the provider is changed to MS Ole DB provider for SQL Server and for the record I also changed the datasource to an ip address:

[image]

I save the Excel sheet, close it and then reopens it. The datasource is still the modified one. However: when I refresh the data and then check the datasource again, it has reverted to the original situation.

So basically the question is: how to permanently change an existing connection?

And now we are at it: any ideas why my colleagues pc keeps complaining about the SQLNCLI11 provider not being registered?

I am using Excel 2016 and the SQL Server version is 2014 SP2.

Thank you for your time

Comment: There are too many things I could think of which could (potentially) dynamically alter the files. So, I would (personally) just go for the simple solution and make sure the connection is what I want by creating a macro: record your doings when creating the correct connection and then you can potentially run this macro each time the file is opened (making sure the connection is correct and the data is updated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found a (dirty) way to get things going again: I renamed the xlsx extension to zip and changed the xl\connections.xml. I changed all the

```
<x15:oledbPr connection
```

elements with the right provider and to store my password. After saving the changes it worked again.

I also found out that if you change an alias in one of your queries, you cannot refresh the data anymore. At first I simply removed the query and re added it. However you can also change this manually in the XML file. Just change the

```
<x15:dbCommand
```

element in the same connections.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention excel 2016, one option is to use Power Query to load your Power Pivot model.  The only downside is going to power query means recreating the connection/table which can be a pain if you already have a lot of calculation/pivot tables created.

When using Power Query it would handle all the connection/data transformation, with power pivot only caring about the returned results set.  This means that you can via editing the query to swap between data source types, e.g. going from excel --> MS Access --> SQL Database as the connection type without having to recreate the connection/tables within Power Pivot.

Most actions in Power Query would be done via the GUI, though sometimes being able to edit the script can be useful.  A good example is referencing a parameter table which holds information like where to connect and filter conditions.

The query script below as an example connects to an excel file, with the location defined as a file variable in the script.

```
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(File_Parameter), null, true),
Data = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
```

I could swap it to using a different parameter and slight edit to the syntax to handle MS Access instead

```
Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(DB_Location), [CreateNavigationProperties=true]),
Data = Source{[Schema="",Item="factSellout"]}[Data]
```